# Closing Form with a button

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a small feature which will look similiar to the PS4 System.
The PS4 system will tell you that there is already a application running and you must close the current one to start the new one.
 I want to go through all my forms and close only one form.

Example: Form1 is my main form: Form2 is the game i started: Form3 is the game i want to start next: Form4 is the small warning which will tell the user to close "Form2" to start "Form3".

My code is closing all forms but i want only close one.

```
private void allapps()
{
    Form[] app = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToArray();
    foreach (Form apps in app)
    {
        if (apps.Name != "XRXFramework")
        {
            apps.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void button11_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allapps();
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you put a breakpoint on `if (apps.Name != "XRXFramework")` and debug? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour

Comment: `allapps` is a horrible function name. First off, it should be capitalized as `AllApps`, second, it should be named as a verb. You should call it `CloseAllApps` or something.

Comment: @AustinWBryan Be careful with making substantial changes to the code in the question. While those changes were valid, syntax-wise, they don't reflect what the asker is using.

Comment: @TiesonT. Okay, I'll try to keep it in mind next time

Comment: If this is a [tag:winforms] application, please [edit] the question to add that tag.

Comment: *"My code is closing all forms but i want only close one."* - then the coded logic is incorrect. You have told it to close all of the forms whose name is not equal to "XRXFramework". So which one do you want to close, and how would you identify that form?

Answer (score -1):

Try to design your application to store a reference to the last open form, so when you create a new one you can check if a the last form reference is not null and trigger your logic to close it.

Or if your intention is to keep a stack of open forms, then store your open forms in a Stack, so you have the ability to push new forms on top of stack or pop recent added forms...

Comment: This worked very well, thank you very much.
i used `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Count() == 1` and
`Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().First().Close();`

Comment: Are all your game forms of type Form2? if yes, you can even simplyfy and just call Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>.FirstOrDefault()?.Close() directly

Comment: But if you have forms of different types, you need to think to another implementation

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: If he just wants to close any form of type Form2, his solution will work and is straightforward. But if he might have form of types Form1,Form2, Form3, etc. I think this is not  a good approach. My suggestion is about implementing a navigation stack of form of any types  (like in mobile apps)